# Swift 2.0: Override error message for superclass

Tags: swift, swift2, overriding

After switching to Swift 2.0

```
  override public func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)  {
    userInteractionBegan(touches.first as! UITouch)
  }
```

produces an error message:

> Method class does not override any method from its superclass

I have no idea why override does not override anymore!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 2, there are changes in the `touchesBegan` method. Now the first parameter is `Set<UITouch>` instead of `NSObject`. So Swift tells you that you try to override a method which doesn't exist. Use `Set<UITouch>` instead:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
                                        ^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift the method signature is changed to become more "swiftier". This is the new method signature you should overrride:

```
override public func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}
```